# How to get every nth row value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement in sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Year] FROM [data_list] ORDER BY [YEAR] ASC;
```

Result:

```
Year
----
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
2026
2027
2028
```

I want list of year in 3 increments. For example:

```
Year
----
2019
2022
2025
2028
```

Comment: Use `%` modulo function. I.e. `where year % 3 = 0`, or rowno, if not every year is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
SELECT [Year] 
FROM (
  SELECT [Year], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Year] ASC) rn 
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY [YEAR]
) t WHERE (t.rn - 1) % 3 = 0
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0a2dda290fd0a7cc58b62709cb41295b)

Comment: You might want to add `distinct` to the inner query.

Comment: @ZoharPeled You're right! I overlooked the `DISTINCT` on the question. Now I understand why you are using `DENSE_RANK`.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is to use a common table expression with dense_rank, and then filter the results by it.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    [Year] int
)

INSERT INTO @T ([Year]) VALUES
(2019),
(2019),
(2019),
(2020),
(2020),
(2021),
(2022),
(2022),
(2023),
(2024),
(2024),
(2025),
(2025),
(2026),
(2027),
(2027),
(2028);
```

The cte and query:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [Year],
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [Year]) - 1 As dr
    FROM @T
)

SELECT DISTINCT [Year]
FROM CTE
WHERE dr % 3 = 0
ORDER BY [Year]
```

results:

```
Year
2019
2022
2025
2028
```

Comment: It worked for me. 
I'm so sorry. I'll add table creation and values in the future. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try it,

```
;WITH CTEs AS 
(
    SELECT *,(CASE WHEN [Year] %3 =0 THEN [Year] END) AS [Year] FROM yourTable
)
SELECT * FROM CTEs WHERE [Year] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Your query will not execute. You are aliasing the column `Year` when there is already a column `Year` in the table

Comment: Yes I know, But Year is a in-built database function name, and it is a sample example of if multiple column in existing table so i have added * conditions.

Comment: My point is there is a column name `Year` in the table and you still name the alias  as `Year`. You should give the alias a different name